# Passing secondaryId from a menu contribution to part creation in Eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am currently trying to fix a regression in our application which appears to be caused by our switch from e3 to using e4 with the e3 compatibility layer.

We have some views which are configured by their `secondaryId`. These views are only created when the user selects a menu option, and we relied on the menu contribution to set the `secondaryId`, so that the view could configure itself according to that information.

With e3, we defined a single `view` in an `org.eclipse.ui.views` extension point in the view plugins `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
   <category id="my.view.category"
             name="My View Category Name">
   </category>
   <view allowMultiple="true"
         category="my.view.category"
         class="my.views.View"
         id="my.views.view.multiple"
         name="My Views View"
         restorable="true">
   </view>
</extension>
```

Then in our application `plugin.xml` we defined menu contributions which referenced this view:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution allPopups="false"
                    locationURI="menu:window?after=showView">
    <menu label="My Menu">
      <command commandId="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView"
               label="Specific View"
               style="push">
        <parameter name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
                   value="my.views.view.multiple">
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.secondaryId"
                   value="viewSpecificData">
        </parameter>
      </command>
    </menu>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

This worked fine. When the user selected the "Specific View" item on the "My Menu" menu, `createPartControl()` was called on class `my.views.View` and `getViewSite().getSecondaryId()` correctly returned `viewSpecificData`, which it could use to configure the view.

In e4 however, this doesn't work. Tracing through the code, the `ViewReference` class no longer explicitly stores the `secondaryId`, instead both `ViewPart`  and `ViewReference` just extract everything after a colon in the `viewId` and return *that* as the `secondaryId`. Thus with our existing `viewId` which didn't have a colon in it, the secondaryId returned was `null`.

I tried removing the `secondaryId` and adding my `viewSpecificData` to the `viewId`:

```
        <parameter name="org.eclipse.ui.views.showView.viewId"
                   value="my.views.view.multiple:viewSpecificData">
        </parameter>
```

But that just meant that when the menu item was selected, an error dialog popped up saying "View could not be found: my.views.view:viewSpecificData", so I added a new view to my application `plugin.xml`

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
   <view allowMultiple="true"
         category="my.view.category"
         class="my.views.View"
         id="my.views.view.multiple:viewSpecificData"
         name="My Views View"
         restorable="true">
   </view>
</extension>
```

This worked, however I have have a dozen menu items which need converting in just the application I'm working on, which means a dozen new views, and a dozen things which need to be kept consistent between two different sections of each application `plugin.xml` file. Not only that but we have two dozen applications build on this framework, so we could easily be talking about hundreds of view which need to be added in our entire codebase.

I can't help but feel that there must be a better way.

So,

- Is there a way to get the `secondaryId` information from the menu contribution into the `viewId` without having to create a new `view` for each?
- Alternatively, is there a way to create a single `view` which will be used whatever the text after the colon is <sup>†</sup>?
- Finally, is there a better way of solving the problem of getting menu commands which launch the same View class but with specific view configurations?

<sup>† I tried adding a view with `id="my.views.view.multiple:*"` already.</sup>

Comment: I suppose you could define your own command and write a command handler which deals with the parameters correctly. For compatibility mode you only need to call the variant of the `IWorkbenchPage.showView` method with a primary and secondary id.